# Google App Engine Fetching URLs in PHP return 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I just created two phps in my project, one php will use the fetch URL services to make a post request to another php, it works fines on my local development server but it doesn't work when i deploy it on the google app engine and return HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable, the UrlFetch daily quota does not exceed.

Here is my code

```
      $postData = Array(
      'myData'      => 'value'
    );

    $context = [
      'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($postData)
      ]
    ];    

    $context = stream_context_create($context);
    $result = file_get_contents('http://myapp.appspot.com/handler.php' , false, $context);
    $serverResponse = json_decode($result, true);
    $serverResponseHttpCode = $http_response_header[0];   

    echo $serverResponseHttpCode;
```

Comment: Google reported an outage a couple of hours after this question was posted : We're investigating an issue with Google App Engine beginning at Tuesday 2015-03-24 13:05 (all times are in US/Pacific)]. We will provide more information shortly within 20 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was your problem](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/15009), SO is not really the place to seek support, but I know that Google refers to Stackoverflow for support.
The only other option is to buy in on Silver or Gold support to have access to the helpdesk.